# Create column in Pandas based on dataframe query condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Title           Pgid    Views30 Title_to
===============================================================================
30  Хо_Ен_Чон       9048639 284950  Чон_Хо_Ён
98  Mail.ru_Group   9018641 153082  VK_(компания)
105 Паша_Техник     9070663 143053  Техник,_Паша
303 Freeware        6166716 79998   Бесплатное_программное_обеспечение
399 СССР            1007    69349   Союз_Советских_Социалистических_Республик
```

The data contains over 1.2 million entries from Wikipedia page data:

- `Title` = page title
- `Pgid` = page ID
- `Views30` = monthly page views
- `Title_to` = title of the page that this page redirects to (or `NaN` if no redirect)

Now I want to make a new column `Pgid_to` with the page IDs of the redirect target pages for all pages with `Title_to` != `NaN`. That is, collect `Pgid` from `Title` = `Title_to` for all entries.

My current solution is straightforward:

```py
def cond(title_to):
    try:
        # get Pgid of page whose title == title_to
        return df.loc[df['Title'] == title_to, 'Pgid']
    except:
        # return NaN on failure to locate
        return np.NaN
# make new column by applying search element-wise    
df['Pgid_to'] = df['Title_to'].apply(cond)
```

However, this algorithm is likely to take polynomial time (N^2), which for 1.2 MM entries means 1.4 trillion operations! Is is possible to optimize? Possibly, is there a vectorized solution?

Answer (score 1):

`np.where()` is vectorized and hopefully will save the day. Kindly try:

```
df['Pgid_to'] = np.where(df[Title'] == df['Title_co'], 'Pgid',np.nan)
```

If you want to compare it against nan:

```
df['Pgid_to'] = np.where(df[Title'].isna(),np.nan, 'Pgid')
```

Comment: `df[Title'] == df['Title_to']` is an incorrect condition, since the values are always different: `Title_to` contains any random value from `Title` or `NaN`. My goal is something similar to SQL: `update Table t1 set Pgid_to = (select Pgid from Table t2 where t2.Title = t1.Title_to) where not isnull(t1.Title_to)`

Comment: So you need `.isin()` ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution by simply merging the dataframe with itself!

```py
df_merged = df.merge(df, 'left', left_on='Title', 
                     right_on='Title_to', suffixes=(None, '_from'))
```

This produces a new dataframe with the 'Pgid_from' column (among others), which can then be used to group the data.

Comment: This is going to be worse than the `apply()`

Comment: It actually works within very good time limits.